# IdentityServer get time taken to verify client

Tags: asp.net-identity, asp.net-core-2.0, identityserver4, asp.net-core-webapi, asp.net-core-2.1

We want to create a secure API, hence we are using IdentityServer to verify our clients.

Here's a snapshot of our code where we setup authentication

```
services.AddAuthentication("Bearer")
    .AddIdentityServerAuthentication(options =>
    {
        options.Authority =
            Configuration.GetSection("Identity:Uri").Value;
        options.JwtBearerEvents.OnMessageReceived= context =>
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Start log time");
            return  Task.CompletedTask;
        };
        options.JwtBearerEvents.OnTokenValidated = context =>
        {
            Console.WriteLine("End log time");
            return Task.CompletedTask;
        };
        options.CacheDuration =   TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0);
    });
```

The authorization works perfectly, no issue with it.

My question:

I want to capture how much time was taken by the identity server to verify bearer token.
As you see my code, I have added callbacks to `JwtBearerEvents.OnMessageReceived` and `JwtBearerEvents.OnTokenValidated`.
I was thinking of putting stopwatch and start the timer OnChallenge func and stop it in OnTokenValidated func.

But when I try to run this, the code never hits `JwtBearerEvents.OnMessageReceived`.

- what am I doing wrong here?
- Is there any other method I need to implement?
- Is there any other/better way to get time taken by identity to verify token?

Comment: You could work out from ASP.Net Core logs how long it took to authenticate. It is worth noting that there is caching around discovery document so you need to take that into account as you deem appropriate.

Comment: Logs don't provide time taken

Comment: They are synchronous though so you can take the timestamps of log entries from auth middleware

Comment: They don't log anything saying when it started verifying the token...so which timestamps entries are you suggesting to check?

Comment: You are right, sorry, ignore me. I thought from somewhere that authentication middleware produces log like this, but looks like it is from the webhost afterall: `info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost[2] Request finished in 284.0746ms 302`

Comment: Are you using reference tokens and thus want to know what the overhead is? If you're not then it'll be an insignificant amount of time as validating a JWT is a lightweight operation vs something like password hashing.